# CS50 mario python less comfortable .rstrip function

Tags: python, cs50

I'm taking the CS50 course and right now I'm on pset6, python Mario code.

For the rstrip() function, it's supposed to remove the new line at the end of the code. I don't know whats going on and its really bugging me (i think its a syntax error but I'm not sure).

Please if any f you could help that would be great!

Note: I am using "+" symbol to represent " " just for personal understanding.

My code:

```
def input_number(message):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            return user_input



height = input_number("Height: ")
while height < 1 or height > 8:
    height = int(input("Height: "))


i = 0
while i < height:
    print("\n")
    x = height-1
    a = 0
    while x>=i:
        print("+".rstrip("\n"))
        x-=1

    while a<=i:
        print("#".rstrip("\n"))
        a+=1

    i+=1
#print("\n")
```

whats getting printed:

```
Height: 5


+
+
+
+
+
#


+
+
+
+
#
#


+
+
+
#
#
#


+
+
#
#
#
#


+
#
#
#
#
#
```

expected output:

```
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The `print(..)` function takes an `end=...` parameter that will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `end=""` in print method rather than using `rstrip` method.

```
def input_number(message):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            return user_input



height = input_number("Height: ")
while height < 1 or height > 8:
    height = int(input("Height: "))


i = 0
while i < height:
    x = height-1
    a = 0
    while x>=i:
        print(" ", end="")
        x-=1
    while a<=i:
        print("#", end="")
        a+=1
    print("")
    i+=1
```

Output:

```
Height: 5
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
```

Explanation:

`rstrip` is used to remove white spaces from end of a string. For example, when we want to remove unwanted white spaces from user inputted string, we can use `rstrip` to do so. Another use case of `rstrip` is to omit white spaces from lines while reading a file.

On the other hand, to format a output string in a desired format we manipulate `print` method. By default, `print` method outputs the values in a separate line.

For example,

```
print("some string") 
print("another string")
```

It will show:

```
some string
another string
```

According to [print method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), we can use string in `end` argument to overwrite the default `end='\n'`.

For example,

```
print("some string", end="......") 
print("another string", end="!!!!!!")
```

It will show:

```
some string......another string!!!!!!
```

Reference:

- [Manual string formatting python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#manual-string-formatting)
- [rstrip documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)
- [print method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: just a follow-up question. Why can I not use the rstrip function? and what's special about this end="" that helped me in this project?

Comment: @codingGUY, thank you for asking for clarification. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you'd like to remove the `\n` at the end of the line.

Instead of rstrip use
`print("whatever you want to output in here like # or +", end = "")`.

The reason why rstrip won't work in this usecase is that it strips the string you passed to it which is "#" or "+". There is no `\n` there, that is added as the end character of print.

```
def input_number(message):
    while True:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        else:
            return user_input



height = input_number("Height: ")
while height < 1 or height > 8:
    height = int(input("Height: "))


i = 0
while i < height:
    print("")
    x = height-1
    a = 0
    # while x>=i:
    #     print("+", end = "")
    #     x-=1

    while a<=i:
        print("#", end = "")
        a+=1

    i+=1
```

Output:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# TODO


while True:
    n = int(input("Height: "))
    if n > 0 and n < 9:
        break

for i in range(0, n, 1):
    for j in range(0, n, 1):
        if (i+j < n-1):
            print(" ", end="")
        else:
            print("#", end="")
    print()
```

here thats my answer to your question.

```
the Output is the same : 
  #
 ##
###
```